# How can I only show specific minute values in input type time in HTML forms?

Tags: html, input, react-bootstrap

I am using ReactJS and react-bootstrap to build a website. I am having an input form of type `time`. As of now on clicking the clock signal, the user is able to select an hour and a minute from 0 to 59. The present form is shown in the image below.

[image]

How can I modify the form such that the user can only select a minute in intervals of 15, i.e. the user should only be shown four possible minute values which are:  0, 15, 30, 45 and is only able to select a value among them. Is this possible?

I tried using the `step` property, but it didn't stopped the user's ability to choose invalid minute values.

The code I have used is shown below. It has been obtained by modifying only the `App.js` of a `create-react-app`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Choose A Time: </Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="time"
          value={time}
          required
          step="900"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setTime(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What value did you put in the `step` attribute? AFAIK, that is how one can control the minutes in input type of `time`.

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem in using Ui library .To solve this problem, I would make selectBox component with html select tag. You can put option tags with the numbers you want in select tag and get the result you want. Also there is another option, you can use that component. The only thing you need to is to check the number your select is what you want or not. But it's not a good solution. It will make user in trouble. I suggest you to follow my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `step` attribute for `time` does not work as you'd expect it to.

If you use arrows to change the time in it, it'll change as you want it to, 00 -> 15 -> 30 -> 45 -> 00.

However, if you allow to user to click and open the dropdown, it shows all options.

This is a drawback for the input type of `time`. I'd advice you to either make a custom select for the time, or use a separate DateTime library like [FlatPickr](https://flatpickr.js.org). Of course, a simple custom dropdown will do if you aren't going to do anything complex.

Comment: If you use arrows to change the time in it, it'll change as you want it to, 00 -> 15 -> 30 -> 45 -> 00... How can I implement this.?

Comment: It's automatic, click on the input field and use the up or down arrow on your keyboard. The time will change as per your used `step` attribute.